# Totally positive approximation to a given matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition

Given a matrix ${\bf M}$, how can we find ${\bf N}$, a totally positive matrix of order 2 which is close as possible to ${\bf M}$ with respect to some norm?

Comment: Do you mean a matrix of rank $2$?  Surely we don't expect $N$ to be a $2\times 2$ matrix.